# How can I define Anti-Aliasing when creating a device in DX9?

Tags: directx, device, sample, antialiasing, directx-9

I am working on a Directx 9 ready project. First of all, my device creation code is as follows:

```
int CGraphicDevice::Create(HWND hWnd, int iHres, int iVres, bool Windowed, int /*iBit*/, int iReflashRate)
{
    int iRet = CREATE_OK;

    Destroy();

    ms_iWidth   = iHres;
    ms_iHeight  = iVres;

    ms_hWnd     = hWnd;
    ms_hDC      = GetDC(hWnd);
    ms_lpd3d    = Direct3DCreate9(D3D_SDK_VERSION);

    if (!ms_lpd3d)
        return CREATE_NO_DIRECTX;

    if (!ms_kD3DDetector.Build(*ms_lpd3d, EL3D_ConfirmDevice))
        return CREATE_ENUM;

    if (!ms_kD3DDetector.Find(800, 600, 32, TRUE, &ms_iD3DModeInfo, &ms_iD3DDevInfo, &ms_iD3DAdapterInfo))
        return CREATE_DETECT;

    std::string stDevList;
    ms_kD3DDetector.GetString(&stDevList);

    //Tracen(stDevList.c_str());
    //Tracenf("adapter %d, device %d, mode %d", ms_iD3DAdapterInfo, ms_iD3DDevInfo, ms_iD3DModeInfo);

    D3D_CAdapterInfo * pkD3DAdapterInfo = ms_kD3DDetector.GetD3DAdapterInfop(ms_iD3DAdapterInfo);
    if (!pkD3DAdapterInfo)
    {
        Tracenf("adapter %d is EMPTY", ms_iD3DAdapterInfo);
        return CREATE_DETECT;
    }

    if (__IsInDriverBlackList(*pkD3DAdapterInfo))
    {
        iRet |= CREATE_BAD_DRIVER;
        __WarningMessage(hWnd, CREATE_BAD_DRIVER);
    }

    D3D_SModeInfo * pkD3DModeInfo = pkD3DAdapterInfo->GetD3DModeInfop(ms_iD3DDevInfo, ms_iD3DModeInfo);     
    if (!pkD3DModeInfo)
    {
        Tracenf("device %d, mode %d is EMPTY", ms_iD3DDevInfo, ms_iD3DModeInfo);
        return CREATE_DETECT;
    }

    D3DADAPTER_IDENTIFIER9& rkD3DAdapterId=pkD3DAdapterInfo->GetIdentifier();
    if (Windowed &&
        strnicmp(rkD3DAdapterId.Driver, "3dfx", 4)==0 &&
        22 == pkD3DAdapterInfo->GetDesktopD3DDisplayModer().Format)
    {
        return CREATE_FORMAT;
    }

    if (pkD3DModeInfo->m_dwD3DBehavior==D3DCREATE_SOFTWARE_VERTEXPROCESSING)
    {
        iRet |= CREATE_NO_TNL;

        // DISABLE_NOTIFY_NOT_SUPPORT_TNL_MESSAGE
        //__WarningMessage(hWnd, CREATE_NO_TNL);
        // END_OF_DISABLE_NOTIFY_NOT_SUPPORT_TNL_MESSAGE
    }

    std::string stModeInfo;
    pkD3DModeInfo->GetString(&stModeInfo);

    //Tracen(stModeInfo.c_str());

    int ErrorCorrection = 0;

RETRY:
    ZeroMemory(&ms_d3dPresentParameter, sizeof(ms_d3dPresentParameter));
    
    ms_d3dPresentParameter.Windowed                         = Windowed;
    ms_d3dPresentParameter.BackBufferWidth                  = iHres;
    ms_d3dPresentParameter.BackBufferHeight                 = iVres;
    ms_d3dPresentParameter.hDeviceWindow                    = hWnd;
    ms_d3dPresentParameter.BackBufferCount                  = m_uBackBufferCount;
    ms_d3dPresentParameter.SwapEffect                       = D3DSWAPEFFECT_DISCARD;

    if (Windowed)
    {
        ms_d3dPresentParameter.BackBufferFormat             = pkD3DAdapterInfo->GetDesktopD3DDisplayModer().Format;
    }
    else
    {
        ms_d3dPresentParameter.BackBufferFormat             = pkD3DModeInfo->m_eD3DFmtPixel;
        ms_d3dPresentParameter.FullScreen_RefreshRateInHz   = iReflashRate;
    }

    ms_d3dPresentParameter.Flags                            = D3DPRESENTFLAG_LOCKABLE_BACKBUFFER;
    ms_d3dPresentParameter.EnableAutoDepthStencil           = TRUE;
    ms_d3dPresentParameter.AutoDepthStencilFormat           = pkD3DModeInfo->m_eD3DFmtDepthStencil;

    ms_dwD3DBehavior = pkD3DModeInfo->m_dwD3DBehavior;

    if (FAILED(ms_hLastResult = ms_lpd3d->CreateDevice(
                ms_iD3DAdapterInfo,
                D3DDEVTYPE_HAL,
                hWnd,
                pkD3DModeInfo->m_dwD3DBehavior,
                &ms_d3dPresentParameter,
                &ms_lpd3dDevice)))
    {
        switch (ms_hLastResult)
        {
            case D3DERR_INVALIDCALL:
                Tracen("IDirect3DDevice.CreateDevice - ERROR D3DERR_INVALIDCALL\nThe method call is invalid. For example, a method's parameter may have an invalid value.");                    
                break;
            case D3DERR_NOTAVAILABLE:
                Tracen("IDirect3DDevice.CreateDevice - ERROR D3DERR_NOTAVAILABLE\nThis device does not support the queried technique. ");
                break;
            case D3DERR_OUTOFVIDEOMEMORY:
                Tracen("IDirect3DDevice.CreateDevice - ERROR D3DERR_OUTOFVIDEOMEMORY\nDirect3D does not have enough display memory to perform the operation");
                break;
            default:
                Tracenf("IDirect3DDevice.CreateDevice - ERROR %d", ms_hLastResult);
                break;
        }

        if (ErrorCorrection)
            return CREATE_DEVICE;
    
        iReflashRate = 0;
        ++ErrorCorrection;
        iRet = CREATE_REFRESHRATE;
        goto RETRY;
    }

    // Check DXT Support Info
    if(ms_lpd3d->CheckDeviceFormat(
                ms_iD3DAdapterInfo, 
                D3DDEVTYPE_HAL,
                ms_d3dPresentParameter.BackBufferFormat,
                0,
                D3DRTYPE_TEXTURE,
                D3DFMT_DXT1) == D3DERR_NOTAVAILABLE)
    {
        ms_bSupportDXT = false;
    }

    if(ms_lpd3d->CheckDeviceFormat(
                ms_iD3DAdapterInfo, 
                D3DDEVTYPE_HAL,
                ms_d3dPresentParameter.BackBufferFormat,
                0,
                D3DRTYPE_TEXTURE,
                D3DFMT_DXT3) == D3DERR_NOTAVAILABLE)
    {
        ms_bSupportDXT = false;
    }

    if(ms_lpd3d->CheckDeviceFormat(
                ms_iD3DAdapterInfo, 
                D3DDEVTYPE_HAL,
                ms_d3dPresentParameter.BackBufferFormat,
                0,
                D3DRTYPE_TEXTURE,
                D3DFMT_DXT5) == D3DERR_NOTAVAILABLE)
    {
        ms_bSupportDXT = false;
    }   

    if (FAILED((ms_hLastResult = ms_lpd3dDevice->GetDeviceCaps(&ms_d3dCaps))))
    {
        Tracenf("IDirect3DDevice.GetDeviceCaps - ERROR %d", ms_hLastResult);
        return CREATE_GET_DEVICE_CAPS2;
    }

    if (!Windowed)
        SetWindowPos(hWnd, HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, iHres, iVres, SWP_SHOWWINDOW);

    //Tracef("vertex shader version : %X\n",(DWORD)ms_d3dCaps.VertexShaderVersion);

    ms_lpd3dDevice->GetViewport(&ms_Viewport);

    m_pStateManager = new CStateManager(ms_lpd3dDevice);

    D3DXCreateMatrixStack(0, &ms_lpd3dMatStack);
    ms_lpd3dMatStack->LoadIdentity();

    ms_ptVS = CreatePTStreamVertexShader();
    ms_pntVS = CreatePNTStreamVertexShader();
    ms_pnt2VS = CreatePNT2StreamVertexShader();

    D3DXMatrixIdentity(&ms_matIdentity);
    D3DXMatrixIdentity(&ms_matView);
    D3DXMatrixIdentity(&ms_matProj);
    D3DXMatrixIdentity(&ms_matInverseView);
    D3DXMatrixIdentity(&ms_matInverseViewYAxis);
    D3DXMatrixIdentity(&ms_matScreen0);
    D3DXMatrixIdentity(&ms_matScreen1);
    D3DXMatrixIdentity(&ms_matScreen2);

    ms_matScreen0._11 = 1;
    ms_matScreen0._22 = -1; 

    ms_matScreen1._41 = 1;
    ms_matScreen1._42 = 1;

    ms_matScreen2._11 = (float) iHres / 2;
    ms_matScreen2._22 = (float) iVres / 2;
    
    D3DXCreateSphere(ms_lpd3dDevice, 1.0f, 32, 32, &ms_lpSphereMesh, NULL);
    D3DXCreateCylinder(ms_lpd3dDevice, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 8, 8, &ms_lpCylinderMesh, NULL);

    ms_lpd3dDevice->Clear(0L, NULL, D3DCLEAR_TARGET | D3DCLEAR_ZBUFFER, 0xff000000, 1.0f, 0);

    if (!__CreateDefaultIndexBufferList())
        return false;

    if (!__CreatePDTVertexBufferList())
        return false;
    
    DWORD dwTexMemSize = GetAvailableTextureMemory();

    if (dwTexMemSize < 64 * 1024 * 1024)
        ms_isLowTextureMemory = true;
    else
        ms_isLowTextureMemory = false;

    if (dwTexMemSize > 100 * 1024 * 1024)
        ms_isHighTextureMemory = true;
    else
        ms_isHighTextureMemory = false;

    if (ms_d3dCaps.TextureAddressCaps & D3DPTADDRESSCAPS_BORDER)
        GRAPHICS_CAPS_CAN_NOT_TEXTURE_ADDRESS_BORDER=false;
    else
        GRAPHICS_CAPS_CAN_NOT_TEXTURE_ADDRESS_BORDER=true;

    //D3DADAPTER_IDENTIFIER8& rkD3DAdapterId=pkD3DAdapterInfo->GetIdentifier();
    if (strnicmp(rkD3DAdapterId.Driver, "SIS", 3) == 0)
    {
        GRAPHICS_CAPS_CAN_NOT_DRAW_LINE = true;
        GRAPHICS_CAPS_CAN_NOT_DRAW_SHADOW = true;
        GRAPHICS_CAPS_HALF_SIZE_IMAGE = true;
        ms_isLowTextureMemory = true;
    }
    else if (strnicmp(rkD3DAdapterId.Driver, "3dfx", 4) == 0)
    {
        GRAPHICS_CAPS_CAN_NOT_DRAW_SHADOW = true;
        GRAPHICS_CAPS_HALF_SIZE_IMAGE = true;
        ms_isLowTextureMemory = true;
    }

    return (iRet);
}
```

This code works without errors. There is no problem. However:

```
ms_d3dPresentParameter.MultiSampleType = D3DMULTISAMPLE_4_SAMPLES;
ms_d3dPresentParameter.MultiSampleQuality = 0;
```

Although it compiles without any problems when I add this, the exe does not open and gives the error "Sorry, your system does not support 3D Graphic....".

I looked in debug and the following part is triggered:

```
case D3DERR_INVALIDCALL:
                Tracen("IDirect3DDevice.CreateDevice - ERROR D3DERR_INVALIDCALL\nThe method call is invalid. For example, a method's parameter may have an invalid value.");                    
                break;
```

I use Windows 10 64bit and 4060Ti Graphic Card.
Updated all drivers.